# How to compare elements of stack and linked list in c?

Tags: c, linked-list, stack

I need to compare to check whether elements are in both stack and linked list or not. I implemented stack using linked list. I created a new method called search_both in a type of void and tried to search.

```
    struct student{
    char name[100];
    char surname[100];
    char roll[10];
    char department[50];
    struct student *next;
};

    struct theStack
    {
        struct student *head;
        struct student *pop;
        struct student st;
    };

struct theStack myStack;

void search_both()
{
    struct student *a;
    struct theStack *x;
    a=malloc(sizeof *a);
    x=malloc(sizeof *x);
    if(a&&x)
    {
        while(strcmp(a->name, x->st.name)==0)
        {
            while(strcmp (a->surname, x->st.surname)==0)
            {
                printf("%s %s and %s %s taking both classes",a->name, a->surname,x->st.name,x->st.surname);
                a=a->next;
                x=x->st.next;
            }
        }
    }
    free(a);
    free(x);
}
```

After edit : 
I allocated memory for a and x variables as:

```
 a=(struct student*)malloc(sizeof *a);
 x=(struct theStack*)malloc(sizeof *x);
```

After changing it the first loop inside if is became runnable but the other while loop didn't execute. In second while loop I'm trying to compare all surnames What must be the wrong part of second while?

Comment: In `search_both`, `a` and `x` both point to uninitialized memory. Also, I don't see a question here.

Comment: You mallocated a,x and then immediately try to strcmp() their members.  That's not going to end well:(

Comment: You missed a sentence after the last one. You created a method and then what? Errors? Problems?

Answer (score 1):

You are not iterating at all, after allocating memory and populating the structs outside the search function:

```
void search_both( struct student * pStudent, struct theStack * pStack) {
    struct sutdent * a = pStudent;
    struct theStack * x;
    while ( a ) {
        x = pStack;       
        while ( x ) {
            if ( strcmp(a->surname,x->st.surname) == 0
                    && strcmp(a->name,x->st.name) == 0 ) 
                printf("%s %s and %s %s taking both classes",a->name, a->surname,x->st.name,x->st.surname);
            x = x.st->next;
        }
    a = a->next;
    }
}
```